# Is there any way to have an applet clear its own cache programmatically?

Tags: java, applet, jvm

My applet currently accesses a url and prints the contents at that url.  The problem is that url is fixed, but that url renders something different depending on the website's state.  My applet will print a cached version of the contents at the url instead of actually retrieving the new one.  I don't want the user to have to restart their browser just to get this applet to work properly and the separate_jvm tag only helps if the user refreshes the page.  If I manually go into the java console and clear the classloader cache that seems to make it work.

Pretty much I want to be able to programmatically clear a JVM's cache.

Comment: Why do you have to use the classloader cache for accessing the URL?

Answer (score 0):

After careful searching I haven not been able to find a solution, but, I was able to remember of the classic timestamp solution.  If I append the timestamp to the url, even if it's not used, it will never have a cache problem.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is set the HTTP 1.1 Cache-Control request header to no-cache.  How you do that depends on the library you are using.  If you are using the Apache HTTP Client, take a look at HttpRequest.setHeader().  Changing the timestamp works, but tends to clog caches with stuff that can't be reused.